# Yet another clang/gcc discrepancy regarding ODR usage?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++, one-definition-rule

Why does this code compile with GCC (4.9 and 5+), but not with clang (3.5-3.9)?

```
void test(const int&) { }
int main() {
  const int x = 42;
  auto f = []{ test(x); };
}
```

I have some vague idea that the discrepancy has to do with ODR (One Definition Rule) usage, but I don't understand that well enough to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: interestingly clang is happy if you make x static

Comment: @RichardHodges Variables with static storage duration don't need to be captured.

Comment: Does anyone else think it is a bit silly that one has to explicitely capture context instead of the compiler figuring it out for us?

Comment: @BitTickler no, explicit capture is a good thing. it prevents accidentally capturing circular references (e.g. when capturing a weak/shared ptr)

Comment: @BitTickler That's the whole point of the capture-default specifiers = and &

Comment: @BitTickler the options are `[=]` and `[&]`  , in this exact case it makes no difference but in general the capture methods differ so the compiler could not 'figure it out'

Comment: What happens if `test` is in another compilation unit, where the compiler can't see into it (and see that it doesn't depend on the identity of its argument)?

Comment: @BenVoigt same deal; gcc constructs a local prvalue temporary from `x` and passes a reference to that temporary to `test`.

Comment: @ecatmur I've been in that world, coding objective-c captures. It's a bad, bad world. c++ has it right.

Comment: This is a good example of how C++ has too many corner cases. (You're using a variable in a lambda expression, so it needs to be captured. But wait, it's a constant, so it doesn't. But wait, it's actually used by reference, so it does.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`x` is odr-used because it's bound to a reference (`test`'s parameter). It therefore must be captured ([[expr.prim.lambda]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#13)):

> If a *lambda-expression* or an instantiation of the function call
>   operator template of a generic lambda odr-uses ([basic.def.odr]) `this`
>   or a variable with automatic storage duration from its reaching scope,
>   that entity shall be captured by the *lambda-expression*.

Violations of this rule, like all other rules in the standard that doesn't say "no diagnostic required" or "undefined behavior", [require a diagnostic](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#2).

GCC, unfortunately, performs constant folding too early, before it could tell whether it's an odr-use or not. This can lead to problems [such as `[&]()->const int & { return x; }` returning a dangling reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70121).

Comment: @M.M you could certainly exploit this to produce the same effect though, right?

Comment: @M.M I'm pretty sure **[class.local]** /1 applies (since a lambda is a local class): *Declarations in a local class shall not
odr-use (3.2) a variable with automatic storage duration from an enclosing scope.*

Comment: @ecatmur have you got a reference for that? In N4140 the term "local class" does not appear in the [expr.prim.lambda] section.  (although this is moot as TC finds that there is an equivalent rule for lambdas specifically)

Comment: @M.M ["The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*."](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#3)

Comment: @T.C. OK. I guess "An implementation may define the closure type differently" is not allowed to extend to it declaring the closure type at file scope

Comment: @M.M "from what is described below". That sentence is not "below".

Answer (score 8):

T.C. has the right diagnosis, here's a clearer bit of legal code where clang does the right thing and gcc doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>

void test(const int&a) { std::cout << "in test() -- " << &a << "\n"; }
int main() {
  const int x = 42;
  std::cout << "in main() -- " << &x << "\n";
  auto f = [&]{ test(x); };
  f();
}
```

gcc prints different addresses for a capture-by-reference variable than the original!

Comment: It's even worse than that; try `int main() { const int x = 42; return [&]{ const int& a = x; const int& b = x; return &a == &b; }(); }` - gcc binds the two references to distinct prvalue temporaries!

Comment: @ecatmur: Sorry for the noise.  It's really hard to see where the lambda ends and main continues again, for code in a comment.  Yeah, that's evil.